# Angular 4 Html Table Group By Column

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am trying to take some flat data coming in an api and displaying it in an html table using angular 4.  I am not sure on how to loop with like a for each.  I have been trying to use an ngFor but not sure how to nest the sub values for matching the grouped value.

API Data example JSON

```
{
     "requestor": "A, Person",
     "dataPoint1": "Data1A",
     "dataPoint2": "Data1B"
},{
     "requestor": "A, Person",
     "dataPoint1": "Data2A",
     "dataPoint2": "Data2B"
},{
     "requestor": "A, Person",
     "dataPoint1": "Data3A",
     "dataPoint2": "Data3B"
},{
     "requestor": "B, Person",
     "dataPoint1": "Data1C",
     "dataPoint2": "Data1D"
},{
     "requestor": "B, Person",
     "dataPoint1": "Data2C",
     "dataPoint2": "Data2D"
}
```

And I am trying to get it to output like this

```
Requestor     DataPoint1    DataPoint2
A, Person
              Data1A        Data1B
              Data2A        Data2B
              Data3A        Data3B
B, Person
              Data1C        Data1D
              Data2C        Data2D
```

TypeScript

```
data = [];

constructor(private service: DataService) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.service.GetData().subscribe(d => this.data = d);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should transform to data in more suitable format like(You can transform this data in component file, Its even better if you send this format from server side only)

```
{
     "requestor": "A, Person",
     "dataPoint1": ["Data1A","Data2A", "Data3A"]
     "dataPoint2": ["Data1B","Data2B", "Data3B"]
},{
     "requestor": "B, Person",
     "dataPoint1": ["Data1C","Data2C"]
     "dataPoint2": ["Data1D","Data2D"]
}
```

After doing this you can have 1 loop for top level(Requestor) and one one loop for datapoint1 and datapoint2

Comment: Unfortunately this is an old legacy database the web-api is coming from.  For me to generate the data this way I would have to structure this in memory at the controller for the web-api.  Would this be the best way to do it still, at the controller?

Comment: Depend on size of JSON. If it is few KB you can do it in UI layer else it is better to do at API layer only.

Comment: Its only about 28KB and should never grow very large.

Comment: 28 kB is not too big for UI. You can transform it in UI.

Comment: This brings me back to my original question then.

Comment: I ended up making like you said in the controller.